# Download pdf file from firebase storage ioinc 5

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, ionic5

I am trying to download pdf file in ionic 5 application, which is stored in firebase storage i tried using filetransfer but file not downloading in my device it gives entry url this

file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/test.pdf

Here the Download function

```
download(downloadUrl: string) {
  console.log(downloadUrl);

   this.fileTransfer.download(downloadUrl,this.file.dataDirectory +'test.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());

    }, (error) => {
  
    });
    
  }
```

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add

**android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"**

inside **AndroidMenifest.xml > application** tag like below screenshot. It's required to add in the android 11 version.

[image]

Comment: After android platform created I have added android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" in android/app/src androidmenifest.xml even after adding this same line file:///data/user/0/io.ionic.starter/files/test.pdf returns

Comment: Here the function        download(downloadUrl: string) {
  console.log(downloadUrl);

   this.fileTransfer.download(downloadUrl,this.file.dataDirectory +'test.pdf').then((entry) => {
    console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());

    }, (error) => {
  
    });
    
  }